# Magento timeout error when adding new attribute set

Tags: php, magento

I'm having an issue adding new attribute sets to Magento.

On the "Add New Attribute Set" page, after entering a name and choosing to base the new set on Default, I click "Save Attribute Set". The page then loads for about 10-15 seconds and displays a white page with this error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in D:\\httpdocs\lib\Zend\Cache\Backend\File.php on line 653

If I return to the "Manage Attribute Sets" page, the new set is included in the list! **However**, when I edit it, the "Groups" panel is blank and all attributes are in the "Unassigned Attributes" panel. This is strange as the Default set has correct groups so it doesn't look like it has copied the set.

Thanks a lot for any help you can offer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you increase the max_execution_time that is usually stored in php.ini, be sure to restart Apache once you do this.  This can also be done via a .htaccess, if you look at the one provided by Magento, I believe there is a line that increases it to 18000 seconds.

Comment: `php_value max_execution_time 18000` is a good idea. It also allows dataflow exports and backups to complete. Anything that has a long execution time is a liability in Magento. If you still have problems with long saves in attribute and category management, your MySQL server is misconfigured or not allowed enough resources. This will eventually result in data corruption if allowed to continue.

Comment: Thank you Vern, this has solved my problem. As this site is on a Windows nox the .htaccess didn't work. I changed it in the php.ini file and restarted IIS. It's now working :)

Comment: No problem.  I thought it was Windows, but I was thinking Wamp, and not IIS.  Glad that all issues are resolved.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent this error you have to change value of [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).